# Using CASE in a sql Select statement with count

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I am trying to execute a `Select` statement which includes multiple tables from a database and which has a calculated column of count added in it. I have problem adding another calculated column where I want to use `CASE` statement.

My code looks as follows:

```
SELECT     
    Customers.FirstName, Customers.LastName, Customers.PrivateNumber, 
    Branches.Name, Pawns.ID, Pawns.StartDate, Pawns.FinishDate, 
    Items.Name, Items.Mass, Items.Quantity, Pawns.CurrentSum, 
    Transactions.[Percent], Currencies.Name as Currency,
    COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY Pawns.ID) AS Cnt, 
    NewDistrPrcnt = (CASE WHEN COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY Pawns.ID) > '1' 
                    THEN Items.Mass/SUM(Transactions.[Percent])*Transactions.[Percent] 
                    Else Transactions.[Percent] End)  
FROM         
    Customers 
INNER JOIN
    Pawns ON Customers.ID = Pawns.CustomerID 
INNER JOIN
    Items ON Pawns.ID = Items.PawnID 
INNER JOIN
    Branches ON Pawns.BranchID = Branches.ID AND Pawns.LocationID = Branches.ID 
INNER JOIN
    PawnTypes ON Pawns.PawnTypeID = PawnTypes.ID 
INNER JOIN
    Currencies ON PawnTypes.CurrencyID = Currencies.ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Transactions ON Pawns.ID = Transactions.PawnID AND Pawns.FinishDate = Transactions.Date
WHERE     
    (Pawns.StatusID = 6) AND (Pawns.FinishDate BETWEEN '15Oct2013' AND '23Oct2013')
ORDER BY 
    Pawns.ID, Branches.Name, Pawns.FinishDate DESC
```

The following error is returned when I try to run the query:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Column 'Customers.FirstName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Can anyone please help me in solving this issue?

Comment: Er, what's up with that date format?  Please tell me you don't actually have a string column with that data (which isn't nicely searchable).  Also, you really shouldn't use `BETWEEN`, [especially in SQL Server](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).  The problem you're seeing is because you have `SUM(Transactions.[Percent])` in your `CASE` statement - if you give us sample starting data and expected results, we may be able to help you better.

Comment: Perhaps you need to `SUM(Transactions.[Percent])` over something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with `SUM(Transactions.[Percent])` .Replace it with window function as : `(SUM(Transactions.[Percent]) over ())` and try as:

```
SELECT     
    Customers.FirstName, Customers.LastName, Customers.PrivateNumber, 
    Branches.Name, Pawns.ID, Pawns.StartDate, Pawns.FinishDate, 
    Items.Name, Items.Mass, Items.Quantity, Pawns.CurrentSum, 
    Transactions.[Percent], Currencies.Name as Currency,
    COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY Pawns.ID) AS Cnt 
    ,NewDistrPrcnt = (CASE WHEN COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY Pawns.ID) > '1' 
                          THEN Items.Mass/(SUM(Transactions.[Percent]) over ())*Transactions.[Percent] 
                          Else Transactions.[Percent] End)  
FROM         
    Customers 
INNER JOIN
    Pawns ON Customers.ID = Pawns.CustomerID 
INNER JOIN
    Items ON Pawns.ID = Items.PawnID 
INNER JOIN
    Branches ON Pawns.BranchID = Branches.ID AND Pawns.LocationID = Branches.ID 
INNER JOIN
    PawnTypes ON Pawns.PawnTypeID = PawnTypes.ID 
INNER JOIN
    Currencies ON PawnTypes.CurrencyID = Currencies.ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Transactions ON Pawns.ID = Transactions.PawnID AND Pawns.FinishDate = Transactions.[Date]
WHERE     
    (Pawns.StatusID = 6) AND (Pawns.FinishDate BETWEEN '15Oct2013' AND '23Oct2013')
ORDER BY 
    Pawns.ID, Branches.Name, Pawns.FinishDate DESC
```